# Client Back Database Repair Fails

Tags: essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

Somehow my client backup database got corrupted.

When I start a repair action, it runs for hours and it fails to repair with the following message:

An unknown error prevented the backup repair process from starting. Make sure that all services are running and then try again.

The progress bar grows and I can see disk activity from the WSSBackupRepair.exe process on Resource Monitor.

How can I find out why it can't repair the backup database?